# Script score query with dense_vector awlays gives 1.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-7.8.1 and following an official sample [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html) to try function for vector fields and all documents are scored 1.0.

I am so confused.Can somebody told me why?Thanks a lot.

I also tried min_score and change the script,but nothing worked.

Sample for create data:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_dense_vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 3
      },
      "status" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "my_dense_vector": [0.5, 10, 6],
  "status" : "published"
}

PUT my-index-000001/_doc/2
{
  "my_dense_vector": [-0.5, 10, 10],
  "status" : "published"
}

POST my-index-000001/_refresh
```

Sample for query

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "filter" : {
            "term" : {
              "status" : "published" 
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'my_dense_vector') + 1.0", 
        "params": {
          "query_vector": [4, 3.4, -0.2]  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My result

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my-index-000001",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "my_dense_vector": [0.5,10,6],
                    "status": "published"
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "_index": "my-index-000001",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "my_dense_vector": [-0.5,10,10],
                    "status": "published"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your script isn't running. the score you see is 1 because your hits are produced from the query alone. have you tried using a "rescore" block in your query or something like:

 "rescore_query" : {
        "function_score" : {
           "script_score": {
              "script": {
                  .....
              }
           }
        }
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After change the HTTP method to POST, it worked.

I don't know if it's because my elasticsearch-head's version is too old.

The official sample is exactly GET.

So I tried to make request by postman,both GET and POST worked.